# Postgres alias select as column not found

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, alias

I have a table `listings` which has a `jsonb` column `mls_ids`.

When I run

```
select jsonb_array_elements(mls_ids) as objects from listings where objects = '{}';
```

I receive this error:

```
ERROR:  column "objects" does not exist
```

I'm sure this is just basic SQL that I'm messing here but I haven't figured it out yet.

What I am trying to achieve in the query is return the rows that have an empty hash as an element in the array.

Comment: You need to use a subquery, CTE, or lateral join to define the column or repeat the expression in the `where`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, I just got it to work using the LATERAL method. I'm debating whether to answer the question myself or just delete it.

Comment: It's probably a good one to answer.

Comment: You should have answered this :)